# Error submitting app: icon missing - but it is there

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to upload my bundle using Application loader but I get an error about the Icon not being properly set in info.plist
And indeed: my info.plist does not contain any app icon settings but I configured the items in MonoDevelop and they show up correctly in simulator and on the iPad.

It is a universal which currently supports iPad only. What am I supposed to define in my info.plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to edit your plist directly.  The settings you make in MD should populate the plist for you automatically.  You can look inside the app bundle generated by MD to verify that this is really happening.

You might also verify that your icon is in the root of your project (not a subfolder) and that you have the casing of the name corrected.  I think that the simulator is more forgiving of improper casing than the real device.

Comment: I'll check that. Is there some sort of analysis tool like the one in Xcode which checks for common issues prior to suvmitting?

Comment: The ApplicationLoader tool spots quite a bit of stuff. It found an icon with the wrong size for me yesterday, XCode hadn't spotted it and it worked in the simulator.